# Juubi and Rikudou's brother?

Tags: naruto

From the current chapters of Naruto, it is revealed, that Rikudou Sennin has a brother who also sealed the juubi in himself. That means there are two juubis in the world. If Madara has/had control of one of them, where could the other be hidden? His presence in the world for now is speculation. But as the Rabbit Goddess had Byakugan, this could mean that this brother may have been the Hyuuga's ancestor, which would mean Senju, Uchiha, and Hyuuga are indeed related, but Hyuuga and Uchiha could never be able to use the other's doujutsu, because of difference in ancestor.

So in essence, I'm asking, where could the second Juubi presumably be, is it not possible that the brother is the Hyuuga ancestor? For now this is all speculation, but I have a feeling that Kishimoto will end this series with a few plot holes, so I want to see other users' ideas on these questions.

Comment: Please split your questions into multiple questions. This makes it easier to select a correct answer. If you ask several questions in one question you will risk having answers that are both correct and incorrect at the same time.

Comment: Kurama is the name of Kyubi (the nine-tails) only. Kurama it/himself used to be a single existance, until the fourth Hokage split it/him in two, to protect Naruto from the full power and evilness of Kurama...

Comment: @Alex-sama: Actually, the Kyuubi would not have existed if it weren't for the Sage splitting his chakra. Kurama wouldn't have existed prior to that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha of course. I didn't think about that before! Even if his brother did split the other Juubi, it may have been 9 different creatures from the Juubi we know.

Comment: obviously as you stated in question from current chapters, maybe the answers will be given later. and considering that this was reveled so much later in the main story, either kishi will create another manga for this or will explain properly in the future. this big plot hole towards end  of series is stupid for a writer. and asking for others opinion is not valid type question as per scope of SE network. discussion type questions are not allowed i think.

Comment: @Sp0T I believe Madara has once said, that speculation is still a good assessment of a question, though. Yeah, it is pretty stupid, since the manga is supposed to end this year. I doubt he will ever answer all the questions that arise.

Comment: I don't think it was in the manga that the Juubi was also sealed inside Hamura (if so, what chapter). They sealed it together but to one place. Right?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are two Juubis, because in the final clash between Ten-Tails and Kaguya's sons, Hagoromo and Hamura, they managed to defeat the beast and sealed it within Hagoromo. However, knowing that his death would unleash the Ten-Tails back into the world where it would continue its rampage and reclaim the chakra that humanity now possesses, Hagoromo separated the monster's chakra from its body and used his Creation of All Things ability to create the nine ,tailed beasts. Hagoromo then used Chibaku Tensei to seal the Ten-Tails' husk, i.e the moon.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a second Juubi.

After they defeated the Juubi and Kaguya, Hagoromo sealed the Juubi within himself.

When he neared the end of his life, Hagoromo split the Juubi into 9 creatures, and sent the empty shell to the moon with Chibaku Tensei.

Based on the fourth databook, Hamura's clan moved to the moon to safeguard the Juubi's empty shell (that worked out nicely for them, now did it?)